# setting sys.path to have the parent module path doesn't import the sub module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

The project is in Python3:

```
Project
|
  Mymodule
  __init__.py
  |  
   submodule1
   __init__.py
   some_script.py
  |
   submodule2
   __init__.py
   myclass.py -> implements MyCLass
```

Whenever I run a script, I start from my Project directory. I always execute from this Project location

In `Mymodule.submodule1.some_script.py`, I want to import `MyClass` inside `some_script.py` which is located in `submodule2`

### Things that work in `some_script.py`

```
from ..submodule2.myclass import MyClass
from Mymodule.submodule2.myclass import MyClass
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid location based relative reference in my script file in my submodules. When ever I try to import a module It should search in the current directory, if not found, the go to `sys.path`.

So my solution is in `my __init__.py` of my `submodule1`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./Mymodule')) -> cwd will be "Project"
```

Now inside my `some_script.py` if I import

```
from submodule2.myclass import MyClass
```

This should work, because I have a sys.path entry to the root/parent module(Mymodule). I have verified this by print(sys.path) in `some_script.py`

This always throws an error:

`ImportError: No module named 'submodule2.myclass`

Why its not considering the `sys.path` to search for the module.

Answer (score 0):

I was able  to figure out the issue. In my sys.path, there was already a similarly named module(submodule2) in a different path way ahead of my current project path. So python was searching file in the first module that it encountered while searching for the module, which was in a different location

print(sys.path)

\somepath: ... : .... : ... :\myproject_path

\somepath -> has module(submodule2) with a similar name

\myproject_path -> has my module with a similar name submodule2